# Making a simple post request with parameters and receiving a response

Tags: http, networking, haskell

I want to duplicate this functionality:

```
curl -d "user=username&passwd=passwd&api_type=json" http://www.reddit.com/api/login/username
```

I have run across at least 3 libraries that offer this functionality in a roundabout way: `http-conduit`, `network-http` and `curl`. What library is the standard for making http requests and how would I use it to make this post request?

I should specify that I want to read the response too.

Answer (score 2):

The standard library is [HTTP](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HTTP). It is shipped with the Haskell Platform.

> The HTTP package supports client-side web programming in Haskell. It
>   lets you set up HTTP connections, transmitting requests and processing
>   the responses coming back, all from within the comforts of Haskell.
>   It's dependent on the network package to operate, but other than that,
>   the implementation is all written in Haskell.
>
> A basic API for issuing single HTTP requests + receiving responses is
>   provided. On top of that, a session-level abstraction is also on offer
>   (the BrowserAction monad); it taking care of handling the management
>   of persistent connections, proxies, state (cookies) and authentication
>   credentials required to handle multi-step interactions with a web
>   server.
>
> The representation of the bytes flowing across is extensible via the
>   use of a type class, letting you pick the representation of requests
>   and responses that best fits your use. Some pre-packaged, common
>   instances are provided for you (ByteString, String.)

If the HTTP package is not suitable for one reason or another, there are many packages on Hackage, as you point out, including a direct curl binding, various high level bindings, and bindings that focus on performance.